# Import node module into front end mocha unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a node server which serves some json models to a javascript front end.

The json models are defined in a module and use module.exports to expose the json object.

The front end code is using requirejs.

Is it possible to import the module into my mocha tests so that I can use the json object defined in the module as my test fixture.

```
define(['{path to fixtures}'], function (fixtures) {
    describe('My Tests', function () {
        var components = fixtures.components;
        ...........
    });
});
```

If I use the above in my mocha test spec I am getting the below error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module

So it is finding the file but not able to use it.

If this is possible how can I do it?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: have you tried to bundle your tests using webpack or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was hoping to avoid another package, but I will take a look.